# How to make application.yml refers to config values that are defined inside another file in Grails 4.0.3

Tags: grails, config, external

I would like to learn an easy way to make Grails application.yml refers to variables inside an external file.

My application is part of a pool of microsservices which refer to a centralized configuration for all of them.

**So, instead of this....**

```
environments:
    intest:
        server:
            servlet:
                context-path: /project/pid
            port: 80
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2017Dialect
            url: jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.199.36:50223;databaseName=DETR;domain=TEST
            username: 'usr_detr'
            password: 'XXXgggvvv'
        rabbitmq:
            connections:
                - name: main
                  host: rabbitmq
                  port: 5672
                  username: 
                  password: 
                  virtualHost: /detr
        icomPath: '/app'
```

**I would like something like this.... Please, observe specifically the database ip line.**

```
environments:
    intest:
        server:
            servlet:
                context-path: /project/pid
            port: 80
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2017Dialect
            url: jdbc:sqlserver://${externalFile.ip}:${externalFile.port};databaseName=DETR;domain=TEST
            username: 'usr_detr'
            password: 'XXXgggvvv'
        rabbitmq:
            connections:
                - name: main
                  host: rabbitmq
                  port: 5672
                  username: 
                  password: 
                  virtualHost: /detr
        icomPath: '/app'
```

Comment: Generally you shouldn't explicitly refer to external files.  More common is just referring to config values that are defined in those files, and then separate from that configure those external files as external config sources.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown thanks for your response. That is exactly what I am trying to do, but I don't know how.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I have just changed the title of this question with your words to make it clearer to be understood.

Comment: Some relevant info is at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.